# Why does black show as brown when computer connected to TV via HDMI

Tags: colors, hdmi, tv

I normally use my computer connected to a DVI monitor using the computer's HDMI out. I tried connecting it to my television and there's a brownish tint to everything (any black backgrounds show up as brown). White is still white. If I use the TV menu, all the colours on the menu show up fine. I have a dual-booting machine with Win7 and Ubuntu. The problem occurs with both OSs, and in fact from the moment the machine's switched on (initial boot, GRUB menu, BIOS settings). The TV has three HDMI ports and I've tried with all, no joy. If I use the TV's VGA port then the colours are fine. All drivers and BIOS up-to-date (from Dell's site). Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** It's worth mentioning that the effect is not subtle: the blacks are displayed as fairly rich browns, so I don't think this is down to a small colour mistuning somewhere.

**Edit 2:** It looks like it might be an issue with Samsung TVs. Here are some issues that sound related:

- http://forums.cnet.com/7723-13973_102-382597.html
- http://forums.cnet.com/7723-13973_102-369862.html
- http://forums.cnet.com/7723-13973_102-313039.html
- http://forums.cnet.com/7723-13973_102-394914.html

#### Details

- PC: zino HD 410
- Gfx: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5450
- TV: Samsung LE32B450C4W

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried any other HDMI device?

Comment: No, I don't have a second HDMI source or cable, so I can't test those two areas further :/

Answer (score 2):

This may be the *colour temperature* setting on the television.  Most televisions have a setting where they can tint the image to change the feel of the image.  Colder, bluer colours enhance darker, more eerie films, whereas a warmer red or brown tint is better for happier more 'normal' television viewing.

Check the TV's menu for possible entries like *Colour Temperature*, *Tint* or *Hue* settings and have a play with those.

Comment: +1, seems like the only option here. If the TV has the options to configure color temperature for HDMI and VGA separately, that would be best.

Comment: Thanks, I've been through all the colour settings on the TV and no luck. Also btw the tint is in no way subtle: blacks are quite a rich brown!